# Python 'Collection' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been trying to simplify the following and have been hitting roadblock after roadblock:

```
students = db.get_collection("students")

student = students.find_one({"student_id": "1007"})
print("\nStudent ID: " + student["student_id"])
print("First Name: " + student["first_name"])
print("Last Name: " + student["last_name"])
student = students.find_one({"student_id": "1008"})
print("\nStudent ID: " + student["student_id"])
print("First Name: " + student["first_name"])
print("Last Name: " + student["last_name"])
student = students.find_one({"student_id": "1009"})
print("\nStudent ID: " + student["student_id"])
print("First Name: " + student["first_name"])
print("Last Name: " + student["last_name"])
```

I found something along the lines of:

```
students = db.get_collection("students")

student = students.find()
for student in students:
     print(students)
```

Comment: What "roadblocks" exactly are you hitting?

Comment: I cannot get the program to query the stored information using the .find() unless i use the find_one() which is not the correct way to query

i get one of the following errors:

index 'student_id' cannot be applied to cursor instances
'collection' object is not iterable
'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please, edit the question to include all relevant information - your code that produce the error, along with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it by using a for loop with a range function that goes through the  student ids one by one.

```
students = db.get_collection("students")

for i in range(1007, 1010):
    student = students.find_one({"student_id": str(i)})
    print("\nStudent ID: " + student["student_id"])
    print("First Name: " + student["first_name"])
    print("Last Name: " + student["last_name"])
```